# I am trying to establish the print date of a very large large antique family photograph

Tags: history, enlarging

I have discovered a large family photograph in my mothers effects which is the same image as a much smaller version.  The small one was taken in 1880 and is about 2 inches by 2 1/2 inches and shows a family group.  The large version, which must at one time have been framed, is attached to card and is about 18 inches wide by 23 inches high.  I am wondering if the large one could have been printed contemporaneously with the small one - so in the 1880s - or was that not possible at the time?  It may have been created later from a negative in the 1910s when the daughter of one of the family sitters was an actress in London.  How could I tell from the print itself?

Comment: The place that did the print has likely put a stamp on the back. Without telling the exact date, that can give you an age bracket: the lifespan of the shop

Comment: Thanks.  The photograph is glued to card - with a couple of inches border to the print, and I am reluctant to try and remove it.  Dont think it is possible to remove without damage.

Comment: Here is a photographic paper process used up to about the year 1900: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albumen_print . That would require a big negative for contact printing.

Comment: Or, Bromide paper largely superseded Albumen in the late 1880's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlarger .

Comment: can you post a picture of the picture? Maybe showing how it is mounted to the card

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I will be able to add a picture of the card and image shortly - need to get it out of storage.